# Convert WindowsPath to PosixPath

Tags: python, windows, posix, pathlib

I am using `pathlib` to manage my paths in my Python project using the `Path` class.

When I am using Linux, everything works fine. But on Windows, I have a little issue.

At some point in my code, I have to write a JavaScript file which lists the references to several other files. These paths have to be written in POSIX format. But when I do `str(my_path_instance)` on Windows, The path is written in Windows format.

Do you know a simple way to convert a `WindowsPath` to a `PosixPath` with `pathlib`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

pathlib has an [`as_posix` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.as_posix) to convert from Windows to POSIX paths:

```
pathlib.path(r'foo\bar').as_posix()
```

Apart from this, you can generally construct system-specific paths by calling the appropriate constructor. [The documentation states](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) that

> You cannot instantiate a `WindowsPath` when running on Unix, but you can instantiate `PureWindowsPath`. [or vice versa]

So use the `Pure*` class constructor:

```
str(pathlib.PurePosixPath(your_posix_path))
```

However, this won’t do what you want if `your_posix_path` contains backslashes, since `\` (= Windows path separator) is just a regular character as far as POSIX is concerned. So `a\b` is valid POSIX filename, *not* a path denoting a file `b` inside a directory `b`, and `PurePosixPath` will preserve this interpretation:

```py
>>> str(pathlib.PurePosixPath(r'a\b'))
'a\\b'
```

To convert Windows to POSIX paths, use the `PureWindowsPath` class and convert via `as_posix`:

```py
>>> pathlib.PureWindowsPath(r'a\b').as_posix()
'a/b'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't seem to work :(
On my python console :

>>> t = Path("foo") / "bar"
>>> str(pathlib.PurePosixPath(t))
. Output : 'foo\\bar'

Comment: @graille Odd, it works for me (the other way round; I’m on macOS), and it *should* work. That said, see update. There’s a more direct way.

Comment: `as_posix` is the correct method here. I can verify that `str(PurePosixPath("some\\path\\on\Windows"))` still uses backslashes, though.

Comment: @AdamSmith That … must be a bug in pathlib. On macOS I get, as expected `str(PureWindowsPath(Path('foo/bar'))) == 'foo\\bar'`, and this is indeed the documented behaviour (although the documentation doesn’t explicitly mention the `__str__` dunder method, but the documentation comment for `Path.__str__` *does* specify this behaviour).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm inclined to agree!

Comment: I’ve changed my mind re: my last comment. This is almost certainly *not* a bug. It works in the direction POSIX➝Windows because `/` is a valid path separator. But `\\` in POSIX is *not* a path separator; instead, it’s a regular path character, so *obviously* `PurePosixPath(r'a\b')` is going to return a (valid) POSIX path containing a *backslash*.

Comment: Typo: `pathlib.path` should be `pathlib.Path`.

Comment: beware that as_posix() returns a string, not a PurePosixPath object

Comment: Can we change from PosixPath to WindowsPath? Anyone?

Answer (score 3):

Python  **pathlib**  if you want to manipulate Windows paths on a Unix machine (or vice versa) -  you cannot instantiate a WindowsPath when running on Unix, but you can instantiate `PureWindowsPath/PurePosixPath`

.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I was looking through the **tensorflow** repository source code and I found this statement `os.path.abspath(path).replace('\\', '/')` and this is the only statement, it is a single line function they are using to convert `posix` path to `windows` path and now I'm kind of confused that how come this statement returns a valid `windows` path.

Comment: windows accepts "/" as valid paths in the NT apis, but not on the older Win32 ones, so it depends on how the application consuming those paths are made